# Why are more attributes added from a CSHTML file when I view it after build?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have inherited an MVC project. I now try to understand the following issue. The code is at the beginning of a simple cshtml file:

```
@model LIS.Models.ClassificationViewModel

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="filter-select filter-exact" data-placeholder="@Language.All" data-empty="zero"><span class="fa fa-exclamation iconColor"></span></th>
            <th>@Language.Name</th>
            etc...
```

After building the project I open the generated web page and take a look at the HTML source.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped tablesorter tablesorter-bootstrap hasFilters" role="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row" class="tablesorter-headerRow">
            <th class="filter-select filter-exact tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-placeholder="Alla" data-empty="zero" data-column="0" tabindex="0" scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" unselectable="on" aria-sort="none" aria-label=": No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" style="user-select: none;">
               <div class="tablesorter-wrapper" style="position:relative;height:100%;width:100%">
                   <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
                       <span class="fa fa-exclamation iconColor"></span> 
                       <i class="tablesorter-icon fa fa-sort fa-lg"></i>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </th>
            <th data-column="1" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc" tabindex="0" scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" unselectable="on" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Namn: Ascending sort applied, activate to apply a descending sort" style="user-select: none;">
               <div class="tablesorter-wrapper" style="position:relative;height:100%;width:100%">
                 and a lot more...
```

As you can see there's a LOT more attributes and elements added afterwards. Can anyone give me a theory or explaination on what's happening with my web code after I build the project? Is it some jQuery that adds all extra information, or is it something that happens during the compilation on the web server?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't definitely a server-side compilation issue.

It looks like you are using a jQuery's plugin named **tablesorter**, which is adding such attributes to your table.